# Sync Framework: SQL Server to SQL Server To SQL Express

Tags: wcf, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm very new to Sync Framework, Still exploring different possibilities. Here is my Scenario.

We need to have an application (SQL Server and ASP.Net) which is hosted on our web server. Users can register and interact with it online. Another Copy of the application will be installed on our Client's Intranet server. Users can be registered over LAN on this server.

A third copy of the Application (SQL Express) will be installed on various laptops and windows 7 tablets. Users will use the application remotely without connectivity to LAN or internet. Once the device is back in network, it will sync data with the LAN server and LAN Server will sync to the Internet server.

I intend to do this using WCF services and Sync Framework for the sake of security, however I'm open for suggestions. Can someone please suggest me the correct way of doing this and point me to some tutorials samples to do this. I've been struggling with samples available online (mainly this one http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-SyncSQL-Server-e97d1208) for a while and still have no success ..

Feel free to shoot any questions and I will answer them as best as I can.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this link and ignore/substitute the Azure specific stuff with SQL Server...it has a good discussion on the WCF specific components... [Walkthrough of Windows Azure Sync Service Sample](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1568.walkthrough-of-windows-azure-sync-service-sample.aspx)